# Do I need to apply for a UK transit visa when I have a visitor visa?

Tags: uk, netherlands, hong-kong, chinese-citizens

I am a Chinese passport holder currently living in the Netherlands with a Dutch residence permit.  I will fly from Amsterdam to London, and immediately transit from there to Hong Kong.  Lugguage would be checked through directly to Hong Kong.

According to the website, I need to apply for a UK direct transit visa.

However, I am currently holding a UK visitor visa, valid for 6 months and for multiple entry. Do I still need to apply for a separate transit visa to get on board in Amsterdam?

Answer (score 1):

No. A visitor visa gives you all the same entitlements that a transit visa does, plus many more. In other words, transit is a "feature" included in the visitor visa.

Comment: Please provide a link or evidence when you state a law or rule - if at all possible, as it helps give confidence for the OP that your answer is factual and based on a rule somewhere.